# Where can I find Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 16 to download and install

Tags: java, java-16

I'm developing mod for Minecraft Forge 1.17 which requires JDK16. I have installed that. I'm using Eclipse and the compiler gives a warning that execution environment is JavaSE16 but no JRE16 found. As far as I know there is no JRE16 installed on my computer. The problem is that I can't find it anywhere.

Looked from Oracle website and Adoptium website. Both offer JDK16, but no JRE16. Where can I find JRE16 to download?

Comment: You don't need JRE 16 if, as you claim, you have installed JDK 16. The JDK includes the JRE. Therefore, I'm guessing that your problem is with the Eclipse configuration. Maybe you could start by posting the actual error message that you are getting. Perhaps a screen capture of your Eclipse showing the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand that a JDK is a superset of a JRE. A JDK = a JRE + a compiler and other tools.

Java 16 is now past end-of-life.

I suggest you move to Java 17, the current long-term support version. You should read the release notes for Java 17. But as I recall migrating from 16 to 17 should be quite simple, without issues.

Several vendors offer binaries and installers for the JDK. Some of those release a JRE as well.

The lost of potential  vendors include Adoptium, Azul Systems, Microsoft, IBM, Red Hat, BellSoft, SAP, Oracle, Pivotal, Amazon, and more.

Some vendors may offers builds for the outdated Java 16. For example, Azul Systems [offers a JRE for Java 16](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-16-sts&package=jre&show-old-builds=true). But such outdated versions are intended only for debugging, not production.

Comment: It should also be noted that the Oracle and OpenJDK download sites do not and never have offered JRE builds for Java 9 or later.  But a JDK can be substituted for a JRE.

Comment: I think that page relates to Java 6.  The supported configurations link points to a page that says: "Oracle Certified System Configurations - Java SE 6"

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download Java](https://www.java.com/en/) to download the Runtime Environment.

Comment: java.com only supports version(s) where Sun-then-Oracle released JRE separate from JDK, now only 8, and OP needs 16.

Answer (score 0):

***The JDK includes the JRE, so you do not have to download both separately.***
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk16-archive-downloads.html

**WARNING**: These older versions of the JRE and JDK are provided to help developers debug issues in older systems. They are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.